# ONVIF implementation using GSoap

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, gsoap, onvif

I am a c++ programmer. I am new to gsoap and onvif protocol.
I need to implement onvif client and server application.I read about gsoap and I did not get clear idea about it.
I am using VS2015 compiler. 
Could anyone give me a breif idea about gsoap.
I am not getting how to set the camera related data (e.g. firmware version, hardware ID of the camera) in my server application. How can I do that?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

gSoap is a tool that transforms wsdl files into c or c++ code, either for a server o for a client implementation of a web service.

Once you add the generated c/c++ code to your project, in your case a client, you'll be able to invoke the generated functions in order to call the webservice, being executed in the IP camera.

A good explaination about using the ONVIF function is given in the ONVIF [application programmin guide](http://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf). Dealing with gSoap is explained in its [documentation](https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html).

Comment: I checked it. But, I am unable to understand how to implement server from scratch. How can I set the details like hradware iD etc (Actually the camera that we are using is not actual IP camera, using FFMpeg we are broadcasting the stream. Using that link we can view the feed. SO indirectly, it is an IP camera). DO you have any sample server side code.

Comment: sorry, I cannot share code. But the documentation has everything you need. Probably you should start with the example of the calculator.

Comment: Do I need to create a WSDL file for my server application?

Comment: Onvif provides the wsdl files for implementing the protocol, it's on www.onvif.org . If you want to develop something on you own, yes, you must write your own files.

Comment: Since I have to write my server side code, I thought of writing my own wsdl file. Or can I use any existing wsdl file?

Comment: There are examples of gSOAP and ONVIF online. I suggest to start with https://www.genivia.com/examples/onvif/index.html and also check out http://shoaib-ahmed.com/onvif-gsoap-in-c-by-example and the ONVIF consortium's documentation.

Comment: I generated .h and .cpp files from https://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl wsdl file. Now I want to implement the PTZ server side implementation (e.g for continuous move left). Is this functionality is already implemented in web service or Do I have to implement it. If yes, where do I have to implement it? Kindly help me.

Comment: If I want to use a customized wsdl, how can I generate one.